# Extract tar the tar.bz2 file error

Tags: linux, fedora, tar

I tried to extract the tar.bz2 file in Fedora 17 OS.  I used the command:

```
# tar -xvjf myfile.tar.bz2
```

I received this error message:

```
tar (child):bzip2: Cannot exec :Nosuch of file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exitng now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar:Error is not recoverable: exitng now
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score -12, accepted):

For `bz2` you need to execute like this,

```
tar -jxvf
```

Alternatively, you can also execute like this

```
bunzip2 myfile.tar.bz2
```

For more information you should check it,

```
tar --help
```

If in doubt, run `file` on the archive to make sure it actually is compressed in `bz2` format.

Comment: I don't believe that you need to follow an order of operations for the `bzip2` format with the `tar` command. Calling `tar -xjf` and `tar -jxf` work. I think the only argument that requires ordering is the `-f` option that requires the file name immediately after it.

Answer (score 90):

Ensure that you have the `bzip2` and `bzip2-libs` RPMs installed.

It looks like the `tar` command defers to the `bzip2` command which the `bzip2` RPM provides (`/usr/bin/bzip2`). In your case, `tar` specifically tries to call `bzip2 -d` to decompress the bzipped archive.

Also, a couple of tips:

- The `-v` option is not necessary. It just gives verbose output, which means that it lists the files that were extracted from the archive. Most of the time this prints useless data to your terminal.
- As @Skynet said, it is helpful to run the `file` command on your bzip2 archive to ensure that it is actually in bzip2 format.
- As @Odin said, it appears that you don't need to specify the `-j` option when extracting the archive, as the `tar` command seems to be smart enough to figure this out.

Answer (score 63):

I solved it using:

```
aptitude install bzip2
```

Comment: followed that and solved the issue, no real knowledge why this solved my issue but it did

Comment: In my case I was missing bzip2, which caused me to get the same errors. Installing bzip2 [apt-get install bzip2] fixed my issue and allowed me to extract my files using the command "tar -jxvf myfile.tar.bz2"

Comment: Refer to the answer from @Kevin S to understand this

Answer (score 15):

I found the same error as you in CentOS 7. It looks like this:

```
tar -jxvf target_gile.tar.bz2
 <br>tar (child): bzip2: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
<br>tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
<br>tar: Child returned status 2
<br>tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Then I installed bzip2 package : `yum install bzip2`

After that, I extracted again using this command: `tar -jxvf target_gile.tar.bz2`

Answer (score 11):

You may need to install the **bzip2**  on your system.

```sh
yum -y install bzip2
```

I got the same problem . I have two server.

A: CentOS 7.6 Min install

B: Fedora 29 Workstation

On B:create a tarball with:

```sh
tar -jcvf  XXX.tar.bz2   /Path_to_my_dir
```

Then scp this tarball to A server to decrompress it, but when I want to decompression it I got the same error.Finally it turns out that, tar could work with **bzip2** but **you have to install it first** .

Answer (score 3):

This worked for my file:

binutils-2.15.tar.bz2 (Found at http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/)

```
bunzip2 your-tar-file.tar.bz2
```

Your file now looks like this:

`your-tar-file.tar`

```
tar xvf your-tar-file.tar
```

File will finish extracting

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install lbzip2 package:

```
yum install lbzip2
```

then untar the file

```
tar file.tar.bz2
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can extract either tar.gz or tar.bz2 with this command:

```
tar -xvf ~/sometar.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 0):

this error come also if you use some wrong alias in your `.bashrc/.zshrc` as:

```sh
alias tar='tar -cf'
```

when you execute in terminal

```sh
$ tar -xf file.tar
```

it's been

```sh
$ tar -cf -xf file.tar

tar (child):bzip2: Cannot exec :Nosuch of file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exitng now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar:Error is not recoverable: exitng now
```

so, you should not use an alias for tar or do

```sh
$ unalias tar
$ tar -xf file.tar
```