# tar (child): lbzip2: Cannot exec: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, teamcity, tar

I am getting the following error when my bash script executes `tar -xf`

```
[21:02:51][Step 2/2] tar (child): lbzip2: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
[21:02:51][Step 2/2] tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
[21:02:51][Step 2/2] tar: Child returned status 2
[21:02:51][Step 2/2] tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
[21:02:51][Step 2/2] Process exited with code 2
```

I did check that I had `bzip2` installed (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40736295/1291717)):

[image]

Not quite sure if I need `bzip2-libs`:

[image]

The weird thing is, when I run the script manually from `sh`, it runs fine! But when I run it via TeamCity (which is running in Docker), it fails with the above error.

The script is literally the following (omitting some details):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
whoami
echo "$USER"
set -e
ScriptFilename=$0
ScriptPath=$(cd $(dirname $0) && pwd)

argn=$#
if [[ $argn != '1' ]]; then
    echo "usage: ${ScriptFilename} phpArchivesDirTarFile"
    exit
fi

phpArchivesDirTarFile=$1

function ExtractPhpArchives {       
    tar -C $ScriptPath -xf $phpArchivesDirTarFile
}

echo "ExtractPhpArchives"
ExtractPhpArchives
```

It results in the following TeamCity output:

[image]

Suspecting a permissions problem, I added "whoami" (which prints "root") and `echo "$USER"` which, a bit surprisingly, prints nothing.

What's more interesting, I have a backup copy or the tar file for which the script runs fine in TeamCity. But when I extracted the tarball contents and archived them again, I was back to the "Cannot exec" problem:

[image]

TeamCity settings:

[image]

Why am I getting this error and what else can I try to debug it?

Comment: HI! Where is your script is executed? On host or in docker container?

Comment: @BorisMarkov, as you can see from the TeamCity settings, it's executed directly on the host.

Comment: @BorisMarkov, sorry, I was wrong before: the TeamCity agent is running in Docker, so the script must be running in Docker too. Does that give you any clues?

Comment: If TeamCity agent is running inside a docker container then you should install bzip2 inside that container

Comment: @BorisMarkov I have this in my .dockerfile: ``RUN yum -y install gcc-c++ make autoconf bzip2 mc file``